# Select all Things in a given list of Categories (or more Categories)

Tags: sql, select, relational-division

Imagine a simple two column table, that has thing_id and category_id. Yep, it's used as a many to many connector between Things and Categories, but matters not, all that is relevant is that we have this table ThingCategory with these two columns.

I would to SELECT from ThingCategory, in a way that, given a list of categories - for example (1, 2, 6, 23) - I am returned all (distinct) thing_ids that are in those categories - (1, 2, 6, 23) - or more categories.

Any approach to this has eluded me, efforts to research how by searching on-line and here, and interactions with ChatGPT ;-).

I can sort of imagine constructing a query by hand for a fixed set. Perhaps sort of like this in a cascading list of subqueries:

```sql
SELECT thing_id
FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id = 23
(SELECT thing_id
FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id = 6
(SELECT thing_id
FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id = 2
AND thing_id IN
(SELECT thing_id
FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id = 1)))
```

But is there a cleaner way, to write a query that can work on the list (1, 2, 6, 23)?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: I appreciate that, I really do. But I have researched this long and hard already in many ways and when discussing a minimal example (say things in Category 1 AND 2) invariably solutions are posited that work for 2 categories. The aim of the question is to make clear how unwieldy and awkward the only solution I have found becomes for an arbitrary list.  I envisage that actually helps clarify the question.

Comment: You want [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/U-iMVSMK)?

Comment: @PonderStibbons Champ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're sure there is no duplicate of (thing_id,category_id)

```
select thing_id
from thingcategory
where category_id in (1, 2, 6, 23)
group by thing_id
having count(*) = 4;
```

Comment: And if there may be duplicate you can use `having count(distinct category_id) = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT thing_id from 
(
SELECT * FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 6, 23)
)
```

Comment: That returns all thing_ids that are in category 1 OR 2 OR 6 OR 23. And I am after thing_ids in category 1 AND 2 AND 6 AND 23, but not limited to those, perhaps in any other catgory as well.

Comment: yes, the where statement in the subquery satisfies the or condition matching and returns every map that contains the category_id in the tuple. Then selecting the distinct thing_id from the seleted pairs. Depending on how you are making the query you just need to change the contents of the tuple

Comment: The subquery will return things in only 1 of those categories. A further constraint on the count - say being 4 or more, fails because a thing in categories (1, 3, 4, 92, 97) will also be returned (satisfies the subquery, matching one of the categories and satisfies the count constraint.

Comment: (
SELECT * FROM ThingCategory
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 6, 23)
)
this subquery will return everything that matches any category_id in the tuple of (1,2,6,23), so if you change the contents of this tuple to (1,3,4,92,97) it will return everything that matches those category_ids.

Comment: True. In which case actually a constraint that the count is 4 would satisfy the question I suspect.